# parse html with NDHpple swift

Tags: html, swift, parsing

i just want to parse a simple Html code using NDHpple

this is my html code:

```
<div id="hdrimg"><img class="icover" src="http://covers27.jpg"border="0" width="90" height="90" ></div><div id="hdrinfo" class="hdrinfo ">
    <span class="name">Test</span>
    <span class="info"></span>
    <span class="info2">test</span>
    </div>
```

to get the class="name" i use :`let xpath = "//span[@class='name']"`but i can not get the `src="http.//cover27.jpg`. i try many syntax to get it but i failed

Comment: clearly `src="http://covers27.jpg"` is an attribute of an `img` rather than a `span` so you should use xpath "//img[@class='icover']" to fetch the `img` element then fetch the `src` attribute from it

Comment: thk cezheng it works